# No Audio in IE when using .play() function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

got some timer up and running and when the time is up, it should play a small soundeffect "beep.wav". It's working in Chrome, Safari, FF, Edge but not in IE. This it what I'm using...

```
function playSound()
{
    var win = new Audio('beep.wav');
    win.play();
}
```

Any solution to bypass IE?

Comment: first I thought you are going to gift me an audi :p

Comment: _bypass IE_. What do you want? to play audio in IE or if it is IE, then not load the page?

Comment: I don't have much use with the audio api but shouldn't your `'beep.wav'` be pointing to a relative path like, `'../sounds/beep.wav'`? Sorry if I'm off my rocker.

Comment: I want it to work in IE also :)

Comment: And the sound does load in all other browsers, so the path is not the problem.

Comment: Which version of IE? `HTMLAudioElement` is only supported in IE11. http://caniuse.com/#search=Audio

Comment: On all versions. I just check with IE11 and even there no audio-file playing. And on the same PC with Chrome it works fine.